# Scanner only searching first line of .txt file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I'm in a beginning programming class, and seem to be having a major issue with searching a text file. What my code should do, based on the assignment:

- Accept input, in this case a name and place that input into a .txt file
- Allow the user to search for a name, or part of a name, and return all lines with matching text.

I have the input portion of the assignment complete, and am on the verge on completing the retrieval portion, but my code only searches the first line of the .txt file. I am able to print out all lines of the .txt file, and if I search for the name in Line 1 of the .txt file, it will print the line correctly. My issue comes when I am searching for a name that is not on Line 1. Below is my code:

```
System.out.println ("Would you like to retrieve names from your index? (YES/NO)");
try
{
    retrieve=input.readLine();
   }
   catch (IOException E)
   {
    System.out.println(E);
   }
  }
 if (choice == 2 && retrieve.equalsIgnoreCase("YES") || retrieve.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
  {
   while (retrieve2.equalsIgnoreCase("YES") || retrieve2.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
   {
     FileReader reader = new FileReader("Name_Index.txt");
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
     String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

     System.out.println ("Enter a string of characters in which to search by or enter \"all names\" f$
     search_term = gatherInput();

     System.out.println("Search results include: ");
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File("Name_Index.txt"));
     inFile.useDelimiter(",");

     while (inFile.hasNextLine())
     {
      list.add(inFile.nextLine());
     }
     Collections.sort(list);    
     if (search_term.equalsIgnoreCase("all names"))
     {
      for (String temp : list)
      {
       System.out.println(temp);
      }
     }
     else if (line.toLowerCase().contains(search_term.toLowerCase()))
     {
       System.out.println(line);     
       bufferedReader.close();
     }
System.out.println("End!");
    System.out.println ("Would you like to retrieve names from your index? (YES/NO)");
    try
    { 
     retrieve2=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException E)
    {
     System.out.println(E);
    }
   }   
    System.out.println("Thank you, come again!");
  }
 }    
   public static String gatherInput()
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_input = scan.nextLine();
    return user_input;
   }
  }
```

I have tried expanding the *while (inFile.hasNextLine())* loop to include the second "if" statement, however that creates an issue for the "all names" search - it returns the entire list multiple times (however many lines are in the file). I have even tried creating another *while (inFile.hasNextLine())* loop within the second "if" statement, and there is no difference in outcome.

I'm so frustrated at this point, because I've been working on this code for over a week, and have reviewed all of my notes and lecture recordings for this assignment with no help. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you reformat you code so that indentation is clear? Also, you have a mysterious `}` after your first catch block... what does it close?

Comment: does "all names" give you a proper output? Also you have not looped with the `BufferedReader` object.

Comment: @Blip Yes. the "all names" request returns the full list. Alphabetized nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading only 1 line of the file

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Why don't you read all lines and store them in a List;

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while(line != null){
   lines.add(line);
   line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

Then to print all lines containing a substring ignorecase:

```
lines.stream().filter(l -> l.toLowerCase().contains(search_term.toLowerCase))
.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is really helping me out, and I finally am starting to understand this project. Can you let me know what is hidden in the arrow operator folds of the substring? I'm getting the following error when trying to compile:

`Name_Index.java:146:
 illegal start of expression
  lines.stream().filter(1->l.toLowerCase().contains(search_term.toLowerCase)).forEach(s->System`

Comment: lines.stream().filter(l -> l.toLowerCase().contains(search_term.toLowerCase()))
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));  Seems i have forgotten search_term.toLowerCase() the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the `readLine()`

For example:

```
  File f = new File(ruta);
            if(!f.exists()) //Error
            else {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       //line = the next line
}
}
```